# How to disable settattr for your class in pre __init__ state just like build-in classes do?

Tags: python, built-in, mutability

So if I try something like this with built-in list before init:

```
list.hack = 'impossible'
```

I get a TypeError.

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'list'
```

But if I make my class that extends built-in list like so:

```
class mylist(list):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

I can oddly do this:

```
mylist.hack = 'haha'
```

And when I would init "mylist", I would have a "hack" attribute within it.

```
x = mylist()
x.hack
[Out]: 'haha'
```

Even though I can't set any new attributes after I init "mylist", I can do so in pre init state.

Is it possible to get same pre init behaviour with custom classes, as there is with built-ins?

Comment: That's not "pre `__init__`". That's the class itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `__setattr__` def is not necessary:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...     pass

>>> MyList.hack = 'haha'
>>> x = MyList()
>>> x.hack
'haha'
```

You are not adding an attribute to an instance (`x`) but to the class (`MyList`). (Some languages have a `static` keyword for these
attributes (C++, Java, PHP, ...).)

It is roughly equivalent to:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...     hack = 'haha' # class attribute, ie. "static"

>>> x = MyList()
>>> x.hack
'haha'
```

Note that this has nothing to do with pre/post init:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...     hack = 'haha'

>>> x = MyList()
>>> MyList.hack2 = 'hehe' # post init
```

You have:

```
>>> x.hack
'haha'
```

But also:

```
>>> x.hack2
'hehe'
```

To summarize, in Python:

- you can add class attributes after the class definition;
- if `x` is an instance of `C` and `attr` an attribute of `C`, then `x.attr` is equivalent to `C.attr`.

---

For the record, you can prevent this flexible behavior using a metaclass:

```
>>> class MyListMeta(type):
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         raise AttributeError()

>>> class MyList(list, metaclass=MyListMeta):
...     hack = 'haha'
```

As expected:

```
>>> x = MyList()
>>> x.hack
'haha'
```

But now:

```
>>> MyList.hack2 = 'hehe'
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
AttributeError
```

Note that you can't set existing attributes either:

```
>>> MyList.hack = 'hehe'
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
AttributeError
```

Remarks:

- Do not do this unless you know what you are doing.
- Do not use this to secure your classes: one can easily bypass this behavior and add class attributes.

Summary of the remarks: **do not do this**.

Comment: Oh wow, I never thought of subclassing type and passing it as metaclass. Thank you for your response and don't worry, I'll do my best not to do anything stupid. I'm just trying to better understand how Python works. Will read more about metaclasses.